# Stripe connect onboarding language GET param

Tags: stripe-payments

Hi I'm creating a onboarding process where user is being redirected to stripe connect onboarding via account link which provides me with link of the following form:

```
https://connect.stripe.com/setup/s/acct_XXX/XYZ
```

Once redirected to this link I'm being presented with the first step of the onboarding but with default US language.

My question is: Is there any parameter I can pass via GET or in any other way to enforce default language to be different?
Just quick NOTE user account has a different Country param than US so that param is not taken into the equation.

Comment: Right now that can't be controlled. It uses the default locale of the browser; and then there's a dropdown in the bottom left of the page to change to a different language.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, unfortunately user who is using our page in Polish and have default browser settings based on os language en-US has very bad expirience as we are onboarding him on our side and is being redirected to stripe which is in English not in Polish and we have no control over it. I hope Stripe will let us control this feature by some sort of GET param.

Comment: same issue here, it would be great that stripe is picking a language of the form based on country param or default_currency, or provide any other option to control the language of the form